# Why Asynchronous Suspension shows up for Google Autherization?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm new at Flutter. I'm trying to develop an app and add google authorization for sign-up/sign-in processes but I keep seeing this error. Can anyone help me?

```
E/flutter ( 9461): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

E/flutter ( 9461): #0 FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:199:7)

E/flutter ( 9461): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 9461): #1 MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29:44)

E/flutter ( 9461): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 9461): #2 MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)

E/flutter ( 9461): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 9461): #3 Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:31)

E/flutter ( 9461): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 9461): #4 main (package:project/main.dart:9:3)

E/flutter ( 9461): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter ( 9461):

I/project( 9461): Thread[6,tid=9481,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xe0241c10,peer=0x12f40000,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

I/project( 9461):

I/project( 9461): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
```

I tried to add Google authentication for sign-in processes. But after I implemented the code I started to keep seeing this error

Comment: u should add an extra package, "Firebase_core". then add this line to ur main.dart file void main() asynce{ await Firebase.initializeApp(); runApp(............. );}

Comment: If you have followed all the instructions of firebase package, in terminal run
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Comment: thanks for the answers but I still see the error. What can I try else?